# How to read images from a local drive into Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I want to run deep learning models in `Google Colab` that has a power GPU support. I am quite new to Colab. Originally I though I could uplod the images using `os.path.join` and `PIL.Image.open` as I did in the environment of `Spyder`. But the `Colab` gives a `FileNotFoundError FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` (the images indeed exist in a local directory). It seems I did not do correctly for the uploading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly upload to colab or upload images to a google drive folder. Then mount that folder in google colab to use it. On the left there is an arrow that opens a sidebar which contains searchable code snippets. Here, you can search for drive to get google drive related code snippets.

This notebook contains some examples,
https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/drive.ipynb#scrollTo=u22w3BFiOveA

The command below list contents of folder named **DeepLearning**,

```
!ls -la "/content/gdrive/My Drive/DeepLearning"
```

Copy contents of drive DeepLearning folder to Virtual Machine in DeepLearning folder,

```
!cp /content/gdrive/My\ Drive/DeepLearning ./DeepLearning
```

Copy contents of Virtual Machine DeepLearning folder to google drive DeepLearning folder,

```
!cp ./DeepLearning /content/gdrive/My\ Drive/DeepLearning
```

You can run `%cd DeepLearning` to change directory to **DeepLearning** folder.

GPU support can be enabled by `Runtime > Change Runtime Type > Hardware Accelerator > GPU`.